# What is the proper syntax when sorting? 1004 Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to use VBA to sort a dynamic range, but I am encountering an error. I am new to VBA, so I think it may be a syntax issue, but I have been unable to find a solution on this site or others.

I have already:

1. Used a worksheet object reference for each range I use.
2. Copied an earlier block of code which works, just changing the worksheet reference to the correct worksheet.
3. Added code to clear my sort fields after I sort each time.
4. And I have moved the `.Apply` to after the `End With`.

None of these worked.

Here is the problem code:

```vb
With Worksheets("Shipping").Sort
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Worksheets("Shipping").Range("A1"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Worksheets("Shipping").Range("C1"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Worksheets("Shipping").Range("D1"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange Worksheets("Shipping").Range("A1:J" & Worksheets("Shipping").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row)
    .Header = xlYes
End With

Worksheets("Shipping").Sort.Apply
Worksheets("Shipping").SortFields.Clear
```

Here is the code which works and comes just before the problem code:

```vb
With Worksheets("Backorders").Sort
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Worksheets("Backorders").Range("J1"),Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Worksheets("Backorders").Range("A1"),Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Worksheets("Backorders").Range("C1"),Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Worksheets("Backorders").Range("D1"),Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange Worksheets("Backorders").Range("A1:J" & Worksheets("Backorders").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row)
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
    .SortFields.Clear
End With
```

Each attempt at debugging, I have received the following error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: It will go through the whole block, but the error pops up when it tries to `.Apply`

Comment: Try to Clear the sort fields before the block too.

Comment: Attempted that as well. It "works" as it doesn't error out, but it clears the sort fields before it has a chance to apply the sort, meaning that nothing is actually sorted.

Comment: Clear before you start adding fields, not after.

Comment: Why did you take the `.Apply` out of the `With..End With`?  Try putting it back in.

Comment: It was just a suggestion I saw somewhere, thought it was worth trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GSerg Clearing the sort before adding the fields seemed to work.

Here is the final code:

```
 With Worksheets("Shipping").Sort
     .SortFields.Clear
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Worksheets("Shipping").Range("A1"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Worksheets("Shipping").Range("C1"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Worksheets("Shipping").Range("D1"), Order:=xlAscending    
     .SetRange Worksheets("Shipping").Range("A1:J" & Worksheets("Shipping").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row)
      .Header = xlYes
      .Apply
      .SortFields.Clear
 End With
```

I am not sure why I needed to do this here when I did not in other sections of my code, but for some reason it was necessary.

Comment: It means you already had some conflicting sorting options specified for that sheet. You can call only Clear once and save the file, then you won't need to call it again before sorting.